# My pygame code will not run, gives me errors

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game where you control a helicopter and dodge other things. This is my code:

```
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
X = 400
Y = 400
play = 1
SCREEN_WIDTH = display_width
SCREEN_HEIGHT = display_height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))


def death():
   print('You died')
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You Died.', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    print('Score: {}'.format(score))

def win():
    global alive
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You won!', True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    alive = False

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        global play
        now = True
        while now == True:
            if play == 1:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 1.png")
            play = 2
            if play == 2:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 2.png")
            play = 3
            if play == 3:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 3.png")
            play = 1
    
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        global play
        now = True
        while now == True:
            if play == 1:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Rocket 1.png")
            if play == 2:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Rocket 2.png")
            if play == 3:
                self.surf = pygame.image.load("Rocket 3.png")

        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
               random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 1
            self.kill()

class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bomb, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
        if play == 1:
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane 1.png")
        if play == 2:
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane 2.png")
        if play == 3:
            self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane 3.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 2
            self.kill()

class Blimp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Blimp, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 35))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Blimp.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)

        def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 3
            self.kill()

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, random.randrange(600, 1000))

player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bomb = pygame.sprite.Group()
blimp = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False
        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_opponent = random.choice([Enemy(), Bomb(), Blimp()])
            enemies.add(new_opponent)
            all_sprites.add(new_opponent)

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    if play == 1:
        pygame.time.wait(500)
        play = 2
    if play == 2:
        pygame.time.wait(500)
        play = 3
    if play == 3:
        pygame.time.wait(500)
        play = 1

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((20,50,80))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        alive = False
        death()

    if score > 100:
        print('You won!')
        print('Score: {}'.format(score))
        win()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I've checked it over a lot, and I didn't see anything wrong. But when I run it, it doesn't work and gives me these errors:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Use the window above to play
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such                 
file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file     
or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file     
or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

So when it says `use the window above to play`, that means it is listening to line 10 in the code. Then, it just spews out all of those errors and the window won't work.
can somebody please help me?
UPDATE: I pressed Ctrl+c and it gave me a new error. I don't know if it is just because I shouldn't have pressed that, but the error it gave me seemed relevant:

```
  File "main.py", line 155, in <module>
    player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)
  File "main.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 2.png")
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: The first error is because ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) can't find your sound card. The second error is your `KeyboardInterrupt` that you sent yourself

Comment: other than the `KeyboardInterrupt`, is the first error a problem?

Comment: Well there might be no sound, but it should not completely break the program imho. I have no experience with `pygame`, though

Comment: Are you able to create a [mre] that still produces the ALSA error but with the smallest amount of code?

Comment: I can't because I don't know where the errors originate. Sorry.

Comment: Do you now how to use a debugger? You could use one to execute the program step by step and see what goes wrong at which line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was with the way I was calling some of the things, like `self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 1.png")` should have been `self.surf = pygame.image.load("Heli 1.png").convert`.